# Sync Shared Variable in Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have created a shared class with a shared variable. My function is supposed to run two parallel processes and find the total number of perfectly square integers. I'm able to get the total number of perfectly square numbers in each array, but when the process is done, I'm not able to get the sum of both of these numbers. Could you check where I went wrong? Creating Shared class was unnecessary but I just did it to check if it would work.
Here is my execution:

```
from multiprocessing import *
import multiprocessing
import math



class Shared:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.total = multiprocessing.Value('f', 0)

    def setMP(self, value):
        self.total.value = value

    def getMP(self):
        return self.total


# global total
# total = multiprocessing.Value('f', 0)          # using a synchronized value for all processes


shared = Shared()
shared.setMP(0)

# function to determine if the number is perfect square
def is_perfect(number):
    if float(math.sqrt(number)) *2 == int(math.sqrt(number))*2:
        return True         # the number is perfect square
    return False

# function to find the total number of perfectly square numbers
def find_perfect(array):
    # loop through each element in the array
    for element in array:
        if is_perfect(element):
            # get value
            shared.getMP().acquire()
            i = shared.getMP().value + 1
            shared.setMP(i)
            shared.getMP().release()
    print(shared.getMP())
            
def perfectSquares(listA, listB):
    # multiprocess 
    p1 = Process(target=find_perfect, args=(listA,))
    p2 = Process(target=find_perfect, args=(listB,))

    p1.start()
    
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    return shared.getMP()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    list1 = [7, 8, 23, 64, 2, 3]
    list2 = [64, 54, 32, 35, 36]
    total = perfectSquares(list1, list2)
    print (total)
```

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running under Windows, a platform that uses `spawn` rather than `fork` to create new processes. What this means is that when a new process is created, execution starts at the very top of the program. This is the reason why the code that creates the new process must be within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block (if it weren't, you would get into a recursive loop creating new processes). But this means that each new process you are creating is re-executing any code that is at global scope *and* is therefore ***creating its own `shared` variable instance***.

The easiest fix is to move the creation of `shared` to function `perfectSquared` and to then pass `shared` as an argument to `findPerfect`. Be aware that you have two processes running in parallel but that one must finish before the other. The first process to finish will most likly print a count of 1.0 or 2.0 depending upon which process completes first (although it is possible that it could even be 3.0 when the two processes finish very close together) and the  second process to finish must print a count of 3.0.

```py
from multiprocessing import *
import multiprocessing
import math



class Shared:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.total = multiprocessing.Value('f', 0)

    def setMP(self, value):
        self.total.value = value

    def getMP(self):
        return self.total



# function to determine if the number is perfect square
def is_perfect(number):
    if float(math.sqrt(number)) *2 == int(math.sqrt(number))*2:
        return True         # the number is perfect square
    return False

# function to find the total number of perfectly square numbers
def find_perfect(array, shared):
    # loop through each element in the array
    for element in array:
        if is_perfect(element):
            # get value
            shared.getMP().acquire()
            i = shared.getMP().value + 1
            shared.setMP(i)
            shared.getMP().release()
    print(shared.getMP())

def perfectSquares(listA, listB):
    # global total
    # total = multiprocessing.Value('f', 0)          # using a synchronized value for all processes
    shared = Shared()
    shared.setMP(0)

    # multiprocess
    p1 = Process(target=find_perfect, args=(listA, shared))
    p2 = Process(target=find_perfect, args=(listB, shared))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    return shared.getMP()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    list1 = [7, 8, 23, 64, 2, 3]
    list2 = [64, 54, 32, 35, 36]
    total = perfectSquares(list1, list2)
    print (total)
```

Prints:

```
<Synchronized wrapper for c_float(1.0)>
<Synchronized wrapper for c_float(3.0)>
<Synchronized wrapper for c_float(3.0)>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the explanation.